# Capture this in lambda attribute inside a templated class vs not-templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, gcc4.9

I have succeeded writing a class like this one, capturing this in a lambda defined as non-static attribute of said class:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct S
{
  S()
  {
    std::cout << "S::S()[" << this << "]" << std::endl;
  }

  std::string y_{"hi mate"};
  int x_;
  std::function<void(int*)> del_{[this](int *ptr)
  {
    std::cout << "Deleting ptr[" << ptr << "] this[" << this << "] this->y_[" << this->y_ << "]" << std::endl;
  }};
  std::unique_ptr<decltype(x_), decltype(del_)> unique_{&x_, del_};
};

int main()
{
  S s;
}
```

This compiles and seems to run just fine.

However, with a templated class, it doesn't work anymore:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename>
struct S
{
  S()
  {
    std::cout << "S::S()[" << this << "]" << std::endl;
  }

  std::string y_{"hi mate"};
  int x_;
  std::function<void(int*)> del_{[this](int *ptr)
  {
    std::cout << "Deleting ptr[" << ptr << "] this[" << this << "] this->y_[" << this->y_ << "]" << std::endl;
  }};
  std::unique_ptr<decltype(x_), decltype(del_)> unique_{&x_, del_};
};

int main()
{
  S<int> s;
}
```

> $> g++ -std=c++1y custom_deleter_template.cpp
>   ~/test custom_deleter_template.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct
>   S::’: custom_deleter_template.cpp:9:3:   required
>   from ‘S<  >::S() [with
>    = int]’ custom_deleter_template.cpp:24:10:
>   required from here custom_deleter_template.cpp:15:35: internal
>   compiler error: in tsubst_copy, at cp/pt.c:12569
>   std::function del_{[this](int *ptr)
>                                      ^ Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate. See
>    for instructions.
>   Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/pyro/ccxfNspM.out file, please
>   attach this to your bugreport.

Before filing a bugreport (which I can't do, they blocked account creation), is it normal that it does not compile, based on what the standard says?

Compiler is g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) 4.9.2, used flag -std=c++1y. Same thing happens with flag -std=c++11.

Comment: Internal compiler errors are always a bug. That should compile as it does in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e113357c1393eb6).

Comment: I can reproduce with GCC 4.9.2 on OS X.

Comment: it does compile in clang :) .

Comment: It also compiles with a more recent g++5.0, so it might be a bug that has already been fixed.

Comment: @dyp : do you mind giving a link to get g++5.0 on linux please? The only mirror I checked had only up to 4.9.x versions.

Comment: works on g++5 on OS X, fails with g++4.9.2

Comment: Compile from source / trunk head :) Or use an online compilation service with recent versions, such as http://melpon.org/wandbox/

Comment: Compiles and works fine with g++ 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in GCC, which is already [being tracked](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61362).

It seems to affect 4.8 and 4.9. As pointed out in the comments this particular example works fine for 4.7 and 5.0. You can see that for yourself [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CYLcJ2hCAgWqYJwu) and play with the different versions of gcc.

However this reduced version of your code with no external dependency still crashes with 5.0:

```
template <typename>
struct S {
  int f{[this](){return 42;}()};
};

int main(){
    return S<int>{}.f; //  should return 42
}
```

I would suggest that you wait for the bug I referenced to be fixed before using your code, or switch to another compiler ;).

Comment: Your code is invalid, and rejected by clang because `Lambda<void(int*)>` is an empty struct and doesn't have any room for storing anything, including the lambda you're passing. It would probably be useful to check if a valid program (just give `Lambda` a templated constructor that does nothing) fails the same way.

Comment: @hvd: You are right about the code being ill formatted, but that is besides the point, GCC should reject it as well, not segfault. This indicates the frontend still has some issues dealing with lambdas in a template context.

Comment: Sure, but it would be a lesser issue if the ice-on-valid is fixed, and only an ice-on-invalid remains, than if there is still an ice-on-valid issue.

Comment: @hvd: fair enough, I updated the example, it still triggers the same error but is now valid.

Comment: @hvd: interesting. I get an error in 20150306: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aDgR5Sev834bhMHd

Comment: How odd. Testing shows that in GCC 5 (20150220), that gives an ICE with `-std=c++14`, but not with `-std=c++11`. In GCC 4.9, it gives an ICE with either `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that I messed up my testing. :)

Comment: @hvd: it seems to fail on HEAD for `c++14`, `c++1y` and `c++1z`.